# how to send a modal form and a normal form together using ajax

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Please
I have a form that takes a parent detail and another form which is a modal form that takes a minimal data of a particular student at the point of creating a parent. I want to be able to send the two details at the same time to the controller that handles it in the backend.
This is what I have been trying :

```
$("#plus").click(function () {
    var student = {
        "firstName": $("#sfirstName").val(),
        "lastName" : $("#slastName").val(),
        "middleName" : $("#smiddleName").val(),
    }
    console.log(student)
});
```

This manages the modal form and this for the normal form on the page:

```
$("#addParent").click(function () {
   var parentForm = new FormData($('#parentForm')[0]);
   parentForm.append("firstName",student[sfirstName]);
   parentForm.append("middlesName", student[smiddleName]);
   parentForm.append("lastName", student[slastName]);
   console.log(parentForm);
})
```

before I will now send the forms as one the back end using Ajax... But it doesn't seem to be working ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix like this:

```
$("#plus").click(function () {
    var student = {
        firstName: $("#sfirstName").val(),
        lastName : $("#slastName").val(),
        middleName : $("#smiddleName").val()
    }  // fixed <-- we create an object literal in javascript with name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces
    console.log(student)
});
```

And then:

```
$("#addParent").click(function () {
   var parentForm = new FormData($('#parentForm')[0]);
   parentForm.append("firstName",student[firstName]);  //fixed typo
   parentForm.append("middlesName", student[middleName]); //fixed typo
   parentForm.append("lastName", student[lastName]); //fixed typo
   console.log(parentForm);
})
```